# After win10 1709 update, console can't display some unicode well

Tags: windows, unicode, windows-console

I write a C gobang program, And I use unicode "┏" "┓" "┗" "┛" "┫" "┣" "┳" "┻" "╋" to draw the board, "Ⅹ" acts as the cursor. Before the 1709 update, the board displays well just as a square, after 1709 updae, the board display like a rectangle.
[image: before update]

[image: after update]

Comment: What does main(1).exe have to do with CMD? It's a console application, not a batch script. Make sure you're using a monospace font in the console, such as Consolas.

Comment: I always think windows console application just display in CMD. So, how to set monospace font in the console, I can only find set font in CMD. @eryksun

Comment: Ok, your question is unrelated to the CMD shell. It uses the same console as any other Windows application, but that's not relevant here. Check the console's current font in the properties dialog on the font tab.

Comment: the shell provides `stdin` and `stdout` for the program and cmd.exe is just one of them. Another being powershell

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc, the shell has nothing to do with that. When the shell runs a console application without starting a new console, it simply waits for the application to exit. For example, CMD's one and only thread will be blocked waiting on the child process handle.

Comment: It's unrelated to font, both of the console use the same font. They both use “新宋体” to display Chinese. @eryksun

Comment: I checked the Unicode East-Asian width of these characters. They're all [A]mbiguous -- i.e. narrow or wide determined by context. I also experimented by setting the console to use typical East-Asian fonts such as MS Mincho and NSimSun and got the same result as you. The grid characters are rendered narrow (1 cell), and the circles and roman numeral Ⅹ are rendered wide (two cells). However, with Consolas -- the default console font for Western locales -- all of the characters are rendered narrow, and there's no misalignment problem. But Consolas doesn't have a glyph for "Ⅹ".

Comment: Yes, it's wired. In win7, the default East-Asian can correctly display all the grid characters and circles and roman numeral Ⅹ are rendered wide (two cells). After win10 1709 update, the display is wired, some just display one cell.

Comment: You could ask Microsoft to fix this inconsistent rendering of ambiguous-width characters -- maybe at the [uservoice.com](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/266908-command-prompt-console-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windo) site. A workaround is to use the legacy console, which you can enable in the console's Properties dialog, on the Options tab.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will make a reply to Microsoft.